# Multicolor bar chart

Tags: highcharts

I wants to apply the multicolor on highchart bar chart which is not stacked I wants to apply multicolor on each bar on specific condition   wants to apply multi color on  highchart Bar chart which is not stacked

[image: example image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/nksudgsp/)    This is the fiddle link, but here it is statcked chart,but I want to do it in normal chart without stacking.

Comment: You can try to apply [gradient](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors)